# Getting "rails new" to work for 2nd application with RVM/ruby 2.1.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a running Ruby on Rails application (RVM, ruby 2.1.0) on a CentOS machine;
I am trying to run "rails new" to create a second application, and I am getting this:

```
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/home/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails-0.9.5/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Most of the answers provided previously are suggesting changing which Rails gem to use, but I don't want to break the running app. How can I get around this?

Update: Thanks to the 2 commenters. I ended up creating a separate login and trying to rebuild the app, so that way there would be no gem overlapping. "bundle exec" doesn't work because I am creating the new app outside an existing bundle. I would still like to understand "what really happened" here. What is the real problem? I don't understand the deeper issue - why I can't have more than one Rails app?

Comment: As you are using rvm, you can try separating the gems for each application with gemsets.

Comment: try `bundle exec rails new ...`

Comment: There has been a recent swell in similar problems with the same ancient version of Rails winding up installed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103346/why-is-bundle-update-installing-ancient-gems and all the other results https://www.google.ca/search?q=rails-0.9.5&oq=rails-0.9.5&aqs=chrome..69i57.1561j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"rails-0.9.5" is a problem. You've somehow wound up with an ancient version of Rails in your gemset. You're going to have to upgrade that.

Comment: thanks very much. I am not sure how that got in there. But I can't rebuild the running production user. I was hoping there was something I could do to get around it, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks for explaining it.